# getting variable name of function caller

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function which will return a new function.
this function should get the same name as the variable.

```
function create(){
    return function(){
        [...]
        this.method = function(){
            // %%% should in this case be Creation
            throw "argument is not instance of %%%";
        }
    }
}
var Creation = create();
var created = Creation();
created.method();
```

when i have this code, i want to get the name of the variable my function is bound to .. is it possible?
I don't want to pass the name in variables

### Update

I am creating Functions which will return a new Instance of a DomainObject ...
like

```
var Dog = Fancy.domain({name:"string",age:"number"}, {hasMany: {children:Dog})
```

which will return a function called "Superclass" and when i now append an instance, which is not an instance of Dog, to the hasMany property ( and call `checkHasMany` ) my logger will say, that children must be an instance of Superclass, but i want to write `Dog`, so the developer can see, which Doman he need to inject

Comment: Objects do not know the names of variables that have references to them.

Comment: Can you use ES6?  In a sense, what you are trying to do is make instances of classes and then decide whether the instances have a certain class.  Read up on ES6 and classes here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: What i am trying to do, is ... look in my question, is too many to write in comment